# How to fix the XML file after you import a project as a Maven project

Tags: java, xml, maven

I imported  a folder inside my Eclipse workspace but I am getting some errors regarding my XML file. When I first import the folder as a Maven project, the first error I get is 'Download sources and javadoc' has encountered a problem. Could not download sources or javadoc.

Then when I look at the file I get an error at my first dependency saying "Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: io.dropwizard:dropwizard-bom:pom:2.0.x was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced".

For my other dependencies, I get errors saying "Missing artifact io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:jar:2.0.x"

I have tried installing mvn and refreshing the project, but none of those worked. Do I need to add anything to the file or do something when I import the folder as a Maven project?

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven- 
v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gamingroom</groupId>
<artifactId>gameauth</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>GameAuth</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>2.0.x</dropwizard.version>
    <mainClass>com.gamingroom.gameauth.GameAuthApplication</mainClass>
 </properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
 </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                         
 implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    <transformer
                         
 implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Try deleting the .m2 folder in Users directory and rebuild the workspace

Comment: There does not exist any version which is called `<dropwizard.version>2.0.x</dropwizard.version>` ...Apart from that you are using many old versions and also a maven plugin as a dependency which is simply wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think I must be in your class because I have been having the exact same problem!

I think I've found a solution to these problems. Edit your POM with the following two changes:

1.) Under the "properties" section, change the dropwizard version from 2.0.x to 2.1.0

2.) Under the "dependencies" section, change "dropwizard-bom" to "dropwizard-dependencies"

That seems to have fixed the issue and I am not getting that error message anymore. I think the problem was, as mentioned by @khmarbaise that the version didn't exist (or maybe just not anymore). The other problem was that starting with version 2.0.0 the "-bom" prefix doesn't include all the dependencies that it used to, so now we need to use "-dependencies" for those.

Here is the dropwizard article that helped me out:
https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/upgrade-notes/upgrade-notes-2_0_x.html#upgrade-notes-dropwizard-2-0-x

Good luck with the assignment, hope this helps!

Edit: Sorry, I put the wrong link in earlier, it's been replaced with the correct one now.